# Error when importing other py files

Tags: add-on

[image]

I want to import some classes from another blender python file, but through from. import IndexOperator as IndexOperator, it can't run normally and there is an error in the picture. I want to ask how to import such a python file correctly.

Comment: the error just says that your *MacroTranscribe.py* file doesn't contain anything named *CR_PT_Panel*. Also note that `import xxx as xxx` does the same thing as just typing `import xxx`

Comment: Ok, now I have found my mistake, I did not register my class in __init__.py, thank you!